# Active Directory Group Members missing in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, user-profile-service, active-directory

I'm wondering if anyone could help me in this situation.

I Can't see any group of AD from SharePoint site Permissions,

AD Configuration

OU

AD Group 1

member 1
member 2
member 3

AD Group 2
member1
member2

Thanks

Comment: I've had this, and the issue was that the AD Group wasn't a Security Group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AD groups, so long as they are security groups (not distribution lists), will appear in people pickers when imported in the User Profile Service application.

AD groups are not expanded when used in SharePoint groups to list out individuals. If you do a check permissions, you can check to see if a user has permissions, and it should show that they have been granted permissions based on the SP group that has the AD group membership.